# Xamarin.Forms add Google AdMob integration

Tags: android, forms, firebase, xamarin, admob

I have in the past successfully implement the Google AdMob, but this time with a new project, it's impossible!

I have error with Google AdMob integration in a blank Xamarin.Forms project.

**In the standard project :**

Have theres Nuget packages already installed :

- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.3.1
- Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991265

Create AdmobControl class
In the MainPage.xaml.cs add the AdmobControl with the banner ad id for Android TEST : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"

In the Android project :

Have theres Nuget packages already installed :

- Xamarin.Essentials 1.3.1
- Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991265

Then install the Nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.Ads 71.1601.0

In the MainActivity, inititialize Ads before Xamarin.Forms.Init, with App id for Android TEST : "" -> empty string

Add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Add INTERNET permission

Add the line in the AndroidManifest.xml between the  tag

Create AdMobRenderer class

**The problem :**

The compilation is ok BUT, when I deploy on app on my device, I have 2 errors :
error: MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method zzc(Bundle) in MediationRewardedVideoAdListener
public class MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor    TestAdMob.Android   C:\Users\TheFloods\source\repos\TestAdMob\TestAdMob\TestAdMob.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\ads\reward\mediation\MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor.java    4

JAVAC0000:  error: MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method zzc(Bundle) in MediationRewardedVideoAdListener
public class MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor            0

Source code available here : https://github.com/TheFloods/XamarinTestAdMob

I have try following theres tutorials :

- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1275283/Xamarin-Forms-Integration-with-Google-Admob
- https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/
- https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/

**Others informations :**

- Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.4
- Windows 10 PRO 1803

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Ads.Lite instead of the classic Ads package ? 
Also this might be something you can refer to => http://www.geojorgx.com/programacion/admob-android-the-easy-way-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Ads depends on `Ads Lite`. Try to add an explicit nuget package reference to `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite`.

Comment: Thank you for your help your two, I have solved the problem like this :
1. Uninstall the Xamarin.Firebase.Ads
2. Install the Xamarin.Firebase.Ads.Lite
3. Add the app ip in the AndroidManifest.xml, after the activity tag
4. Install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite, then it works!

A question, why we need to install manually the package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite if it's already in dependencies of the Xamarin.Firebase.Ads.Lite ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help you two.
I have solved the problem like this :

1. Uninstall the Xamarin.Firebase.Ads
2. Install the Xamarin.Firebase.Ads.Lite
3. Add the app ip in the AndroidManifest.xml, after the activity tag
4. Install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite, then it works!